# How to create a dynamic String in SAS?

Tags: sas

I have to create Dynamic string according to different inputs. It will be more clear in below example.

I will get two input

1. Number of zero - 4
2. Length of String - 10

then I have to prepare the string like below

(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1).

I know that we have to put some code in the question, but I am new to coding and SAS and I am not able to start with anything. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Are you familiar with a data step, can you write a loop to generate those values into a data set?

Comment: https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/sas/modules/ or Coursera has free SAS training courses FYI.

Comment: What are you going to do with that string?  Why does it need to be a string instead of just a dataset with 10 observations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is simple method to do it in a data step.

```
data test;
 input nzero totaln;
 length string $200;
  do i=1 to totaln;
    string=catx(',',string,i>nzero);
  end;
  string=cats('(',string,')');
  put string=;
  drop i;
cards;
4 10
5 6
7 7
0 10
;
proc print; run;
```

Result:

```
Obs    nzero    totaln    string

 1       4        10      (0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1)
 2       5         6      (0,0,0,0,0,1)
 3       7         7      (0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
 4       0        10      (1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
```

Or you could make a little macro to generate it.

```
%macro generate(nzero,totaln);
%local i sep;
(%do i=1 %to &totaln;&sep.%eval(&i>&nzero)%let sep=,;%end;)
%mend generate;
```

Test results:

```
205   %put %generate(4,10);
(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1)
206   %put %generate(5,6);
(0,0,0,0,0,1)
207   %put %generate(7,7);
(0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
208   %put %generate(0,10);
(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
```

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thank Tom.. You are the saviour :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use either a macro or a data step to make it dynamic. see following code:

```
options merror nomlogic mprint nosymbolgen;
/*Input number of Zeroes and length of string*/
%let num_zero=5;
%let strln=8;

/*Automatic calculation of length including commas*/
%let len=%eval(&strln+(&strln-1));

data str;
length strval $&len;
 num_z=symget("num_zero");
 stln=symget("strln");
 num_1=stln-num_z;

 do i=1 to num_z;
    strval=catx(",",strval,"0");
 end;
 do j=1 to num_1;
    strval=catx(",",strval,"1");
 end;
 drop num_z stln num_1 i j;
run;

proc print data=str; run;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also achieve this with the `repeat()` function instead of using a loop.  I thought that may simplify things, but for this exact request, it still ends up a little messy:

```
data want;
  length x $200;
  num_zero = 4;
  length_of_string = 10;  
  x = cats('(',substr(cats(repeat('0,', num_zero-1), repeat('1,', length_of_string-num_zero-1)),1,length_of_string*2-1),')');
run;
```